Drools Eclipse Plug-in 7.46.0Final seems to be missing the guided editor (.brl) under the Rule Resource wizard
The ultimate goal here is to have access to a user-friendly way to edit .drl files. This Eclipse-based IDE would be ideal, especially for the features of being able to identify DRL syntax, provide an outline, and offer a guided rule editor. I installed the Drools plugin from this update site in Eclipse version 2024-06.
All the wizards mentioned in the JBoss documentation linked above (Decision Table, DSL, Drools Project, Workflow, Rule Resource) are present except for the Guided Rule, which was the main draw of the whole plug-in. I'm assuming it should be under Rule Resource, but the only options Eclipse provides under 'Type of rule resource' are New DRL (rule package) and New Rule (individual Rule).
Additionally, the Outline feature for .drl files doesn't seem to be working (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.ConstraintBuilder$Holder).
Does anyone have any suggestions on 1. where I can find the Guided Editor (if it wasn't in the update site despite the Jboss documentation stating it has been a feature since version 4, etc.), and 2. how to get the Outline working?
Any help would be immensely appreciated!

The documentation is for a different version than you installed, 5.2.0.Final compared to 7.46.0.Final. Perhaps they dropped that feature?

@nitind I tried installing 5.2.0Final as well, but the Guided Rule feature didn't appear.
